# How to use azure pipeline to deploy jar files to azure artifact using maven task

Tags: maven, azure-devops, pom.xml, azure-artifacts, azure-pipelines-tasks

I created an azure artifact and add it to pom.xml and I configure ~/.m2/settings.xml in the agent machine with the token. and when I deploy locally it is work but when I use the maven task in the azure pipeline this error appears. user has all permissions

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0:deploy (default-deploy) on project my-server: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact:pom:1.0 from/to artifact authorization failed for https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/, status: 403 Forbidden - User '7ba7a839-2613-4554-84a4-4aa2d4cf4162' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'AddPackage'. (DevOps Activity ID: 46D5F76C-E82C-48C8-8D63-4269F3CE4F65) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

i try in windows it worked successfully but i use Linux centos7 as agent to run my pipeline

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a [**Maven Authenticate task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/maven-authenticate-v0?view=azure-pipelines) before the [**Maven task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/maven-v4?source=recommendations&view=azure-pipelines).

When running the pipeline job on the agent, the **Maven Authenticate task** will search for the **`settings.xml`** file in the current user's home directory on the agent machine. For Linux and Mac, the path is **`$HOME/.m2/settings.xml`**. For Windows, the path is **`%USERPROFILE%\.m2\settings.xml`**. If the **`settings.xml`** file doesn't exist, a new one will be created at that path for use.